# Serving static content alongside thymeleaf templates with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-boot

I'm having trouble sonfiguring Spring Boot to use thymeleaf and still serve static content. I have two directories in my resources dir: "/static" and "/templates". According to the Spring Boot documentation, thymeleaf should find thymeleaf templates in the templates directory by default. I am getting a 404 though when I try to use a template.

Relevant code from my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("index.html");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ModelAndView test() {
    return new ModelAndView("test");
}
```

index.html is in resources/static and test.html is in resources/templates.

index.html works fine, but if you try to open /test in your browser, it throws a 404 saying that the thymeleaf template could not be found.

I really appreciate any help. I'm stumped.

Comment: Please post your thymeleaf configuration as well.

Comment: Could you please post your Spring Boot configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Any pages that are not going through the ThymeleafViewResolver(your /resources/static) need to be removed.

```
 /**
 * Configures a {@link ThymeleafViewResolver}
 * 
 * @return the configured {@code ThymeleafViewResolver}
 */
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver()
{
    String[] excludedViews = new String[]{
        "/resources/static/*"};

    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    /*
     * This is how we get around Thymeleaf view resolvers throwing an error instead of returning
     * of null and allowing the next view resolver in the {@see
     * DispatcherServlet#resolveViewName(String, Map<String, Object>, Locale,
     * HttpServletRequest)} to resolve the view.
     */
    resolver.setExcludedViewNames(excludedViews);
    return resolver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just returning the String name of the template and not ModelAndview?
And have your ModelAttributes annotated as indicated in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#model-attributes)?